# Ratio of random variables converging to infinity in probability

Tags: probability-theory

My question is pretty similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495234/does-fracx-ny-n-xrightarrowp0-if-y-n-converges-in-probability-to-in?).

> Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are positive random variables satisfying $X_n \to c$ in probability and $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely, where $c$ is a positive constant. Does $X_n/Y_n$ converge to infinity in probability?

I know that if $X_n/Y_n$ did converge in probability, it would have to be to infinity because some subsequence would converge almost surely, and by uniqueness it would have to be to $c/0 =\infty$. I'm definitely missing a simple way to bound
$$\mathbb{P}\left(  \frac{X_n}{Y_n} > K \right)$$
or some basic application of continuous mapping.

Comment: Well, you might start with the inclusion $$\{|X_n-c|\leqslant |c|/2,|Y_n|\leqslant |c|/(2K)\}\subseteq\{|X_n/Y_n|>K\}$$ Please report here where this leads you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence of random variable $\{Z_n\}$ converges in probability to a random varibale $Z$ iff every subsequence of $\{Z_n\}$ has a further subsequence converging almost surely to $Z$. Now every subsequence of $\{Y_n /X_n\}$ has a further subsequence converging almost surely to $0$ because every subsequence of $\{X_n\}$ has a further subsequence converging almost surely to $c>0$ and $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely. This proves that  $\{Y_n /X_n\}$ converges in probability to $0$ so $\{X_n /Y_n\}$ converges in probability to $\infty $.

Comment: Nice! This was my initial approach but I wasn't able to justify your first sentence. For future readers, it is proved in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773881/a-sufficient-condition-for-convergence-in-probability

Comment: Is it additionally possible to prove that the convergence happens almost surely?

Comment: @Nitin No. Let $\{X_n\}$ be independent random variables taking values $\frac 1 n$ and $1$ with probabilities $\frac 1 n $ and $1-\frac 1 n$ respectively. Let $Y_n=\frac 1 n$. Then $\sum_n P\{X_n =\frac  1 n\} =\sum_n \frac 1 n =\infty$ . By Borel Cantelli Lemma  there is probability 1 that $X_n=\frac 1 n$ for infinitely many values of $n$. It follows that there is probability 1 that $\frac {X_n} {Y_n}=1$for infinitely many values of $n$. Thus $\frac {X_n} {Y_n}$ does not tend to $\infty $ with probability 1. But $ P\{|X_n-1| >\epsilon \}=\frac 1 n \to 0$ so $X_n \to 1$ in probability.

Answer (score 0):

What it means "{Xn/Yn} converges in probability to ∞"?
lim_{n goes to infinity}Pr(|X_n/Y_n - infinity|>epsilon)=0
it means X_n is unbounded? Or something else?
There is a better way to write this?
Best

Comment: These are several questions. Not an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1849123)